# Как убрать Swagger Petstore из своего проекта

Tags: swagger, openapi

В spring проекте перешел со swagger v. 2 на springdoc-openapi (swagger v. 3), все настроил, все работает, но по при использовании по умолчанию в URL добавляется index.html, т.е. начинаю работать с http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, но после перехода по ссылкам URL изменяется на http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html#/... , и самое главное, что по индексу http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html# загружается Swagger Petstore
[image: проект-пример в моем проекте]

Подскажите пожалуйста как удалить это проект-образец из моего кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается добавлением параметра springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url = true в спринг конфигурацию yml/properties

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте изменить index.html в swagger ui

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "xxxx.openapi.yaml", -- тут нужный вам yaml
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout"
      })
      // End Swagger UI call region

      window.ui = ui
    }
</script>
```

результат я в ручную убрал, но поверьте там мой yaml файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тем более что на самом сайте тоже показывают как пользоваться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Редактирование внешней библиотеки выглядит костыльным вариантом для коммерческой разработки, такую проблемную вещь хотелось бы отключать в конфигурации, странно если разработчик это не предусмотрел

Comment: Вообщето это не внешняя библиотека а статичный сайт причем опен сорс. Можете оставить и пользоваться так как удобно.

Comment: Добавил описания чтоб совесть не мучала на счет костылей.

Comment: Спасибо за подробные комментарии, но мне все равно не понятно куда и как это все нужно применить, я и с java работаю совсем недавно, а тут нужны какие-то манипуляции с js , чувствую себя совсем дураком, что даже по инструкции не могу понять, что имел ввиду разработчик

Comment: Давайте перейдем в чат

Comment: ли сделайте поиск по проекту https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json и замените его на нужный вот и все

Comment: такой способ я понял, но это ведь будет локальное изменение исходников и когда я выложу проект на сервер он притянет оригинальный index.html ?
или мне нужно создать внутри проекта какой-то конфигурационный файл в котором должен быть отражен этот параметр?

Comment: в чат еще не переводится обсуждение

Comment: ну да пока так сделайте так как в предыдущем коменте